# How to configure Flume with Kafka channel without source?

Tags: apache-kafka, channel, flume

It complains if a source is not specified in the configuration. According to doc :

The Kafka channel can be used for multiple scenarios:

1. With Flume source and sink - it provides a reliable and highly
   available channel for events
2. With Flume source and interceptor but no sink - it allows writing Flume events into a Kafka topic, for use by other apps
3. With Flume sink, but no source - it is a low-latency,fault tolerant way to send events from Kafka to Flume sinks such asHDFS, HBase or Solr

https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html

I'm interested in the scenario 3 however there is no example for that in official flume doc.

Regards

Comment: Why not just use Kafka Connect and the HDFS connector?

Answer (score 0):

flume agent source can be omitted in flume config on newer versions of CDH (5.14 in my case). Only a warning is issued.

Answer (score 0):

you can provide some dummy name for the source like:

```
agent.sources = dummySource
agent.sinks = hdfsSink
agent.channels = kafkaChnl
```

and just provide the configurations for hdfsSink and kafkaChnl